# XmlNode.SelectSingleNode returns element outside current?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

my problem is like this. Let's say i have xml like this

```
<root>
  <child Name = "child1">
    <element1>Value1</element1>
    <element2>Value2</element2>
  </child>
  <child Name = "child2">
    <element1>Value1</element1>
    <element2>Value2</element2>
    <element3>Value3</element3>
  </child>
</root>
```

I have a method that gets as parameter XmlNode "node". Lets say "node" has value "child1" Then i try like this:

```
node.SelectSingleNode( "//element3" );
```

The problem is this code returns element3 from "child2". What i want is if there is no child "element3" of "node" to return null so i add it by hand.
Best Regards,
Iordand

Comment: That's an abbreviated absolute expression. It would be expanded to `/descendant-or-self::node()/child::element3`. Meaning: *from the document root of the context node through all its descendant nodes, select a child element with QName equal to `element3`*

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The XPath expression you have isn't what you want.

Replace it with this:

```
node.SelectSingleNode( "element3" );
```

And you'll get the result you're looking for.

Comment: Or alternatively "./element3" as it may help to make it clear what it means.

Comment: Just a one more thing to ask if "element3" is not direct child of "child" but there is another node in between what xpath to use ?

Comment: @lordanTanev: You can put the // between the node you're currently on and the node you want, like this: `.//element3`.

Answer (score 12):

The following work perfect when i want to run xpath on the specified node.

```
XmlNodeList nodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes(".//Child");
```

Answer (score 8):

The "//" is a global look up.

What you'll need to do is get a list of all children

```
XmlNodeList nodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//Child");
```

loop through that list and do a

```
XmlNode node = nodes.SelectSingleNode("element3");
```

This will return null if it's not there, and will step through every child looking.

Comment: `"element3"` did not work for me. `".//element3"` did though.

Answer (score 3):

the problem here is the XPath expression you are using, try it without the '//'. Like that:

`node.SelectSingleNode( "element3" );`

Read more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/xpath_syntax.asp) .