# Parsing XML with namespace with PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath

I need a little help with understanding of an XML in PowerShell.
I have several XML files like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog xmlns="http://www.example.com/xml/catalog/2006-10-31">
    <product product-id="11210">
        ...
        <available-flag>true</available-flag>
        <online-flag>false</online-flag>
        <online-flag site-id="ru">true</online-flag>
        <online-flag site-id="fr">true</online-flag>
        <online-flag site-id="uk">false</online-flag>
        <online-flag site-id="de">true</online-flag>
        ...
    </product>
    <product product-id="50610">
        ...
        <available-flag>true</available-flag>
        <online-flag>true</online-flag>
        <online-flag site-id="ru">false</online-flag>
        <online-flag site-id="fr">true</online-flag>
        <online-flag site-id="uk">false</online-flag>
        <online-flag site-id="de">fasle</online-flag>
        ...
    </product>
    <product product-id="82929">
        ...
        <available-flag>true</available-flag>
        <online-flag>true</online-flag>
        <online-flag site-id="ru">false</online-flag>
        <online-flag site-id="fr">true</online-flag>
        <online-flag site-id="uk">false</online-flag>
        <online-flag site-id="de">true</online-flag>
        ...
    </product>
</catalog>
```

I need to get the values of two elements in PowerShell:

- `<online-flag>` (without `site-id` attribute)
- `<online-flag site-id="ru">`

for the product with `product-id="50610"`.

I have the following code:

```
$Path = "C:\Temp\0\2017-08-12_190211.xml"
$XPath = "/ns:catalog/ns:product[@product-id='50610']"

$files = Get-ChildItem $Path | Where {-not $_.PSIsContainer}

if ($files -eq $null) {
    return
}

foreach ($file in $files) {
    [xml]$xml = Get-Content $file
    $namespace = $xml.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI
    $ns = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($xml.NameTable)
    $ns.AddNamespace("ns", $namespace)
    $product = $xml.SelectSingleNode($XPath, $ns)
}
```

Several questions:

1. With this code I am able to select the needed product node. PowerShell shows:

   ```
   online-flag        : {true, online-flag, online-flag, online-flag...}
   ```

   But how then I can select the values of the needed `online-flag` elements (if it is possible both ways: XPath one and the object one)?
2. Is it possible to select a node in the "object" way? Like this:

   ```
   $product = $xml.catalog.product |
              Where-Object {$_."product-id".value -eq "50610"}
   ```
3. If I have several files, what is the best way to select filename, global online-flag (without attributes), specific online-flag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use two different XPath expressions:

1. for selecting a node without a particular attribute:

   ```
   //ns:product[@product-id='50610']/ns:online-flag[not(@site-id)]
   ```
2. for selecting a node with a particular attribute value:

   ```
   //ns:product[@product-id='50610']/ns:online-flag[@site-id='ru']
   ```

You can select nodes relative to an already selected node by making the XPath expression relative to the current node (`.`):

```bsh
$XPath = "/ns:catalog/ns:product[@product-id='50610']"
...
$product = $xml.SelectSingleNode($XPath, $ns)
$product.SelectSingleNode("./ns:online-flag[not(@site-id)]", $ns)
$product.SelectSingleNode("./ns:online-flag[@site-id='ru']", $ns)
```

If you need result data consisting of the filename and the two node values I'd recommend building custom objects:

```bsh
$files | ForEach-Object {
    [xml]$xml = Get-Content $_
    ...
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
        'Filename'  = $_
        'online'    = $product.SelectSingleNode("./ns:online-flag[not(@site-id)]", $ns).'#text'
        'ru_online' = $product.SelectSingleNode("./ns:online-flag[@site-id='ru']", $ns).'#text'
    }
}
```

Using dot-notation and filtering via `Where-Object` should be possible, but I wouldn't recommend it. I find XPath far more efficient.

Comment: Hello Ansgar! Thanks for your answer. I already mentioned that dot-notation is working and I agree that it is not convenient. The issue with your example is that my xml files a quite big and selecting two nodes will take time. Is it possible to select a product first like in my example and then use XPath to select the values of online-flag elements? What will be the XPath in this case?

Comment: I tried all the following with no luck:
$product.SelectSingleNode("/ns:product/ns:online-flag[@site-id='ru']", $ns),
$product.SelectSingleNode("/ns:online-flag[@site-id='ru']", $ns),
$product.SelectSingleNode("/product/online-flag[@site-id='ru']"),
$product.SelectSingleNode("/online-flag[@site-id='ru']").
This $product.GetElementsByTagName("online-flag") works. But the result is not a singe value but a list of values.

Comment: Found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238201/xmlnode-selectsinglenode-returns-element-outside-current

Comment: It is needed to use $product.SelectSingleNode("ns:online-flag[not(@site-id)]", $ns) or $product.SelectSingleNode("./ns:online-flag[not(@site-id)]", $ns) to search in the current node. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think that a namespace is `<xml><ns:node>val</ns:node>`? I cannot see it in the `xmlfile`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the data I need with the "object" way:

```
$product = $xml.catalog.product | Where-Object {$_."product-id" -eq "50610"}
$of = $product."online-flag"
$glblsid = $of | Where-Object {$_ -is [System.String]}
$specsid = ($of | Where-Object {$_."site-id" -eq "ru"})."#text"
```

But I don't like the way I managed to do this. Is there a more convenient solution?

And answer to the second question is yes - see the first line.

Answer (score 1):

To complete this topic. I measured the performance of 3 methods: dot style, XPath on the file and XPath on the node. There is no significant differece between them.
Here are the details.

I parsed 2 times 2 files 60MB each.

1. Object style (dot style)

   ```
   ...
   $StartTime = Get-Date
   foreach ($file in $files) {
       [xml]$xml = Get-Content $file

       #Object style
       $product = $xml.catalog.product | Where-Object {$_."product-id" -eq "50610"}
       $of = $product."online-flag"
       $glblsid = $of | Where-Object {$_ -is [System.String]}
       $specsid = ($of | Where-Object {$_."site-id" -eq "ru"})."#text"
       Write-Output "$($file.Name) $glblsid $specsid"
   }
   $EndTime = Get-Date
   $TimeSpan = New-TimeSpan -Start $StartTime -End $EndTime
   Write-Output $TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds
   ```

   Results:

   ```
   PS> .\ParseXML2.ps1
   2017-08-10_190159.xml false false
   2017-08-11_190203.xml false true
   36269,535
   PS> .\ParseXML2.ps1
   2017-08-10_190159.xml false false
   2017-08-11_190203.xml false true
   36628,3304
   ```
2. XPath on the file:

   ```
   ...
   $StartTime = Get-Date
   foreach ($file in $files) {
       [xml]$xml = Get-Content $file

       #XPath on the file
       $namespace = $xml.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI
       $ns = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($xml.NameTable)
       $ns.AddNamespace("ns", $namespace)
       $glblsid = $xml.SelectSingleNode("/ns:catalog/ns:product[@product-id='50610']/ns:online-flag[not(@site-id)]", $ns).'#text'
       $specsid = $xml.SelectSingleNode("/ns:catalog/ns:product[@product-id='50610']/ns:online-flag[@site-id='ru']", $ns).'#text'
       Write-Output "$($file.Name) $glblsid $specsid"
   }
   $EndTime = Get-Date
   $TimeSpan = New-TimeSpan -Start $StartTime -End $EndTime
   Write-Output $TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds
   ```

   Results:

   ```
   PS> .\ParseXML2.ps1
   2017-08-10_190159.xml false false
   2017-08-11_190203.xml false true
   36129,1368
   PS> .\ParseXML2.ps1
   2017-08-10_190159.xml false false
   2017-08-11_190203.xml false true
   38890,3014
   ```
3. XPath on the node:

   ```
   ...
   $StartTime = Get-Date
   foreach ($file in $files) {
       [xml]$xml = Get-Content $file

       #XPath on the node
       $namespace = $xml.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI
       $ns = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($xml.NameTable)
       $ns.AddNamespace("ns", $namespace)
       $product = $xml.SelectSingleNode("/ns:catalog/ns:product[@product-id='50610']", $ns)
       $glblsid = $product.SelectSingleNode("ns:online-flag[not(@site-id)]", $ns).'#text'
       $specsid = $product.SelectSingleNode("ns:online-flag[@site-id='ru']", $ns).'#text'
       Write-Output "$($file.Name) $glblsid $specsid"
   }
   $EndTime = Get-Date
   $TimeSpan = New-TimeSpan -Start $StartTime -End $EndTime
   Write-Output $TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds
   ```

   Results:

   ```
   PS> .\ParseXML2.ps1
   2017-08-10_190159.xml false false
   2017-08-11_190203.xml false true
   33477,1708
   PS> .\ParseXML2.ps1
   2017-08-10_190159.xml false false
   2017-08-11_190203.xml false true
   34116,7626
   ```